# AVL Tree Modification

Tags: avl-tree

Suppose we have a modified AVL Tree, in which we allow the subtrees to have a height difference of 2 (instead of the standard 1). The operation time would now be log(n+1) which is still O(log n).
Would coding such a tree be significantly different than a standard AVL Tree?
Would it be as efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be harder to balance, since when deleting a node you could end up with two subtrees of height difference 4.

Comment: Would the code then be the same as with the standard only it would take more time to balance? or would the code be different? if so, how much different?

Comment: I expect the code to be more complicated. In classic AVL, there is a single and double rotation, with such a height difference, I'd thing thre would be more different patterns which need different rotation scheme.